# Script push from C# to Php not working on application

Tags: c#, php, sql-server, unity-game-engine

Okay I am using Unity To create my application and MSSQL for the database in between them both i have a PHP Exchange server.

So basically I am having a problem with this piece of code

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class NewSession : MonoBehaviour {
    string userLoginFile = "http://"ServerIP"/UnitySQL/NewSession.php?";
    public UnityEngine.UI.Text NewSess;     

    string userid = "";
    string session = "";

    void OnGUI()
    {
        session = NewSess.text;
        userid = PlayerPrefs.GetString ("UserId");
    }



    public void Insert()
    {
        if (session == "") {
            StartCoroutine (LoginUser (userid));
        } else {
            print("DAMNSON");
        }
    }




    IEnumerator LoginUser(string user)
    {

        WWW login = new WWW (userLoginFile + "UserId=" + user);
        print (userLoginFile + "UserId=" + user);
        yield return login;
        if (login.error == null)
        {

            string[] credentials = login.text.Split('/');

            foreach(string str in credentials)
            {
                string[] creds = str.Split ('=');

                for(int i=0; i < creds.Length; i++)
                {
                    print ("winner");
                }


            }
        }

    }
}
```

Now I don't know why its having this problem because it works fine when i use localhost and have the php exchange on my server i can clearly see the scripts print is correct because if i copy and paste that into the address header it does what its supposed to no problem.
Here is the PHP Script

```
<?php 
    $userid = $_REQUEST['UserId'];

    $user = 'user';
    $pass = 'Pass';
    $server = 'IP';
    $database = 'MyTable';

// No changes needed from now on
    $connection_string = "DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=$server;DATABASE=$database";
    $conn = odbc_connect($connection_string,$user,$pass);
    /*$q = "DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[InsertAnswersCheck]
        @varQuestionOptionId = '$QOI',
        @varUser = '$userid'
SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value";*/
    $q = "INSERT INTO usersession (UserId) VALUES ($userid)";
    $result = odbc_exec($conn,$q);
    $num_rows = odbc_num_rows($result);

    if($num_rows > 0)
    {

    } else {

}
?>
```

It's been a problem for sometime but i cant figure out what is wrong. If anyone can help that would be fantastic.

Please Note It works with the same script on my localhost if set it will require the user to login twice. But when i do it on the server script it will just stick you in a loop until you copy and paste the print code.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know, but you could try:

1. Open in browser whatever your `print (userLoginFile + "UserId=" + user);` prints out.
2. Put `print(login.text);` after `yield return login;` (inside the next `if`).
3. Put `else` you your `if (login.error == null)` with `print("Err: " + "login.error.ToString());`
4. I don't see any `echo` in your PHP script.

Output form 1 and 2 should be identical.

Comment: ill try this i put a hotfix in my program and i am updating the svn so itll be some time before i can use it again. it works when i do it like this application.OpenURL("etc/UnitySQL/newsession.php?Userid=$userid")

Comment: It doesnt provide any information inside the console from print(login.text); like its not blank or anything its just not there